# Pyinotify / Watchdog triggers a modify event twice on one edit

Tags: python, watchdog, pyinotify

I am trying to start a python script everytime is a certain file modified. To be accurate, I have a device on Raspberry Pi's serial ports which writes data into a text file (*test.txt*) . I have tried both tools - Watchdog / Pyinotify. Everytime the file is modified (triggers event Watchdog: `on_modified` / Pyinotify: `IN_MODIFY`), it makes duplicate trigger. I have tried every other method, even `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` as some people suggest, but this doesn't work at all. 
Does someone know, how can just a single event be triggered on one file update?

My code using Pyinotify (a bit edited tutorial file):

```
import pyinotify,subprocess
def onChange(ev):
    cmd = ['/usr/bin/env', 'python', 'doThisFile.py', ev.pathname]
    subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
wm.add_watch('/home/pi/test.txt', pyinotify.IN_MODIFY, onChange)
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
notifier.loop()
```

or Watchdog:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        subprocess.call("/home/pi/doThisFile.py")
        print("Code started")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: Is `IN_ONESHOT` implemented?

Comment: No, nothing like this is not... [Pyinotify events](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Events-types)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while using `pyinotify`. But changing `IN_MODIFY` to `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` solved the issue. You can get more info from this [answer](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=faq&lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

This probably because of the text editor which was used for editing your source code.
solution: calculate the time between 2 events, for example, If the events trigger too frequently, exit the handler from one of the events.

```
class SubEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self._time0 = self.getTime()
    def on_modified(self, event):
        time1 = self.getTime()
        if (time1 - self._time0) < 5:
            exit(0) # not sure it will exit properly
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 events that you are getting are:

1. The file was modified
2. The directory was modified

If you run the [demo code](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) and then in a touch a file in the directory being watched, you'll see the following output:

```
2022-11-04 10:28:45 - Modified file: ./test
2022-11-04 10:28:45 - Modified directory: .
```